# Menu item in my application; no interaction occurs

Tags: android

While doing some research on android, I came across DrawerLayout and navigationView for menu.
Implemented a simple navigation with sliding menu on my application going through a tutorial.
Menu shows up as desire but I can't interact. 
I'm not getting any kind of action nor it gets highlighted when I touch item in my menu. For a life of me, I can't find out the error. No error shows on compile time or run time. Nothing in debugger.

> Code for my main activity:

```
        mDraw = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDraw, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDraw.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        mainNavigationMenu = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navId);
        mainNavigationMenu.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        Log.i("Flag",""+item.getItemId());
                        return false;
                    }
                });

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

> Here is the XML side of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.bikenmaharjan.priceapp.HomeActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navId"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="220dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/upc" />


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/scan" />

                </FrameLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="goocr"
                    android:text="Scan receipt" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Product"
            android:textSize="28sp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> Here is the Menu item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/addProduct"
        android:title="Add Product"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/black"
        />

    <item android:title="Help"
        android:id="@+id/help"
        />

    <item android:title="Sign Out"
        android:id="@+id/signOut"
        />

</menu>
```

Comment: Please post the complete layout.

Comment: I have edited to include whole of XML file.

Comment: The drawer in a `DrawerLayout` must be listed last inside the `<DrawerLayout>` tags. Move the `<NavigationView>` to after the `<LinearLayout>`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the layout. So inside linearLayout has its own problem, read from stackOverFlow that NavigationView has to be a children of DrawerLayout. I changed accordingly and it worked now. Much appreciated for help. :)

Comment: Yeah, don't put it inside the `<LinearLayout>`. It goes _after_ it. Glad you got it working. Cheers!